# How I use LaTeX to write limit equations?

Tags: math-operators

How can I use LaTeX code to write limit equations? I am mainly facing at the point where I am to assign the "x tends to" part.

Comment: That would be covered in any reasonable LaTeX intro document, like lshort on CTAN. `\lim_{x\to\infty}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use LaTeX to write the limit equations, without calling any extra packages. Using daleif's example in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267185/how-i-use-latex-to-write-limit-equations#comment640765_267185):

[image]

```
%pdfLaTeX

\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

$\lim_{x\to\infty}$\\[3cm]

$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `\mathop` here? `\limits` can be used directly: `\lim\limits_{...}`. This is also the default for `\displaystyle`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek You are right, I removed that `\mathop` part.