# Undefined control sequence errors in overleaf

Tags: compilation-error, debugging, undefined

I am getting " Undefined control sequence. " errors in 3-4 parts of my latex code when using overleaf.  I have loaded amsmath in my preamble. I am unable to understand what is the cause or how can I fix it. I am sharing the code segments which the error points to below:

First occurrence:

```
\begin{equation*} \small
    n(\ell)= \frac{k\log(\ell)}{\max\limit_{(\gamma,q_{sp})}
    h\Big(E\Big[e^{-\frac{\gamma}{V  \sigma^{2}P+\sigma_{w}^{2}}}\Big]\Big)- 
    E\Big[h\Big(e^{-\frac{\gamma}{V  \sigma^{2}P+\sigma_{w}^{2}}}\Big)\Big]}
\end{equation*} \normalsize where $E(.)$ denotes the expectation for  $V \sim 
 \operatorname{Bin}(k, q_{sp})$, $q_{sp}$ is the probability  $\gamma$ denotes threshold.
```

second occurrence:

```
\begin{equation} 
    n(\ell) \geq \frac{k\log(\ell)}{\max\limit_{(\gamma,q_{sp})}h\Big(E\Big[e^{- 
    \frac{\gamma}{V  \sigma^{2}P+\sigma_{w}^{2}}}\Big]\Big)-E\Big[h\Big(e^{- 
    \frac{\gamma}{V  \sigma^{2}P+\sigma_{w}^{2}}}\Big)\Big]}.\label{equ}
\end{equation}
```

third occurrence:

```
  \begin{equation}
    C=\max\limit_{(\gamma,\textbf{q})} I(\Tilde{\textbf{X}};Z) \label{sumcap}
    \end{equation} where $\textbf{q} =\{q_{a_1} \ldots q_{a_k}\}$ are sampling 
    probabilities of   $\{a_1 \ldots a_k\}$, i.e., $X^{a_i}  \sim Bern(q_{a_i})$  
    such that  $X^{a_i}\ind X^{a_j}  $ $\forall i,j \in  \{1,\ldots k\}; i\neq j$.
```

I feel like everything is right. But, somehow its not. Can someone help me resolve this please?

Comment: The full text of the error should tell you what command is not defined, as explained here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Errors/Undefined_control_sequence. 

The most likely problem is `\limit` - do you mean `\lim` here? `\limit` seems to be the only command in the first sample not included in base latex or `amsmath`, and its present in each example.

Comment: you can not use ` \small` in math

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full error message for the first error is:

```
<argument> \max \limit 
                       _{(\gamma ,q_{sp})} h\Big (E\Big [e^{-\frac {\gamma }...
l.7 ...{V  \sigma^{2}P+\sigma_{w}^{2}}}\Big)\Big]}
                                                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Notice: "The control sequence at the end of the top line..."  So it's pointing us to `\limit`, which should probably be `\lim`.

Comment: [or `\limits`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/267185)

Comment: @DaiBowen `\limits` does seem to make more sense, as there's no `\to` involved.